# Windows could not start the SQL Server Express on local computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have an exam on SQL tomorrow and I have no idea what to do, I need help as quick as possible. here's the error I get:

[image: print screen]

Comment: So, what does `EventLog` say?  `windows key + R` `eventvwr.msc` `ENTER`

Comment: Under application, it says: `The log scan number (204:272:1) passed to log scan in database 'master' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.`

Comment: and under system it says: `The SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service terminated with service-specific error WARNING: You have until SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) to logoff. If you have not logged off at this time, your session will be disconnected, and any open files or devices you have open may lose data..`

Comment: Try this - http://mywindowsblog.com/?p=638

Comment: The best way will be to reinstall sqlexpress. Seems like your master database is corrupt which is not good and not easy to recover.

Comment: This usually occurs when the master.mdf or the mastlog.ldf gets corrupt . In order to solve the issue goto the following path

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL  , there you will find a  folder ” Template Data ” , copy the master.mdf and  mastlog.ldf  and replace it in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Data folder .

Thats it . Now  start the MS SQL service and you are done .

Answer (score 4):

Your `master` database is corrupt. You have to restore one from a backup, or reinstall sqlexpress.

Answer (score 2):

Run this in cmd C:\Windows\System32\eventvwr.exe

That will open the Event Viewer. In there you will find more details on why SQL didn't start. There is no way of telling just from the screenshot you sent. Error code 3417 is a bit generic, so please paste the full detail of the error once you get it from the log.

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific? Are the logs i posted above not the right ones? if so, where do i find the right ones? under what tab? thanks

Comment: anyone? i have an exam tomorrow and i have to solve this or i wont be able to study..